# Why does post request work much faster from the second call?

Tags: swift, post, nsurlrequest, nsjsonserialization

I launch the app. Press the button which call this function, wait 2-3 seconds and than get the JSON. Then I press it again, wait 0-1 and then I get the JSON. Can you explain me the reason why it's happening and how can I avoid it?

```
public func serverUserRegister(userPhone: String?, userEmail: String?, completionHandler: @escaping ((String) -> ())) {

    if let phone = userPhone {
        if let email = userEmail {

            let url = URL(string: "https://example.com/service.php")!
            let session = URLSession.shared
            let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url)
            request.httpMethod = "POST"
            request.cachePolicy = NSURLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
            let paramString = "phone=\(phone)&email=\(email)"
            request.httpBody = paramString.data(using: .utf8)

            let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
                guard let _: Data = data, let _: URLResponse = response, error == nil else {
                    return
                }
                if let json = try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .mutableContainers) as? NSDictionary {
                    if let jsonStatus = json?["status"] as? String {
                        completionHandler(jsonStatus)
                    }
                }
            }

            task.resume()

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This may or may not be relevant to your situation but when i do non-production development I typically use a free-tier server on Azure to host my web API until its complete. Since I'm using free-tier services, Azure will shut down my API when its not in use... so my first API call takes forever as Azure has to spin up a new copy of my service. Each subsequent call is fast.

Comment: This can also happen with Heroku free servers, for example.